# Excel 2007/MS Query Using 1 table to filter another, partial matching

Tags: excel, excel-2007, where-clause, ms-query

I have a table of BOMs (Bill of materials).

A customer sends me a list of parts and I want to have Excel filter the table to just display those boms, but our part number contains REVs, the customer's entry does not. Is there an easy way to filter the table doing partial matching in MS Query?

For example, the part numbers in our table of boms looks something like:

```
02-60745-30 B
02-60785-20 D
02-60785-20 E
```

the customer sends us:

```
02-60785-20
```

Without the rev.

Doing a simple join in MS Query doesn't work, is there an easy way to do this, or should I go through the customer list and just add the rev? (1000+ parts, would take a while) Is there an easier way?

Here's the Database query from Excel file:

Looks weird:

```
SELECT `'BOM Query$'`.BKBM_PARENT, `'BOM Query$'`.`BKBM_PROD_LINE^`, `'BOM Query$'`.BKBM_COMPONENT, `'BOM Query$'`.MTIC_PROD_DESC, `'BOM Query$'`.MTIC_PROD_TYPE, `'BOM Query$'`.BKBM_QTY_REQD, `'BOM Query$'`.BKIC_PROD_UM, `'BOM Query$'`.BKIC_PROD_DPTNT, `'BOM Query$'`.MTIC_PROD_SUBST_2, `'BOM Query$'`.MTIC_PROD_SUBST_3, `'BOM Query$'`.MTIC_PROD_SUBST_4, `'BOM Query$'`.MTIC_PROD_SUBST_5, `'Filter List$'`.Column1
FROM `M:\Inventory\BOMCheck\Evo BOM Query.xlsx`.`'BOM Query$'` `'BOM Query$'`, `M:\Inventory\BOMCheck\Evo BOM Query.xlsx`.`'Filter List$'` `'Filter List$'`
WHERE `'Filter List$'`.Column1 = `'BOM Query$'`.BKBM_PARENT
```

Comment: Probably, I just need to take our BOMs and only display the ones the customer is asking for. Problem is I can't do it by exact match, gotta match the part# + rev. No idea how I can do that.